# LayoutPanel with right alignment

Tags: gwt, layoutpanels

I'm using a layout panel with some layers. One of the layers is quite simple but I want it to have a float: right on the  element. But this is actually not working because subwidgets are styled with `style="postition: absolute; left: 0px; ..."` which overrides the styling and so the subpanels/widgets will always be placed on the left. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your element to your layout container, did you try [setWidgetHorizontalPosition](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html) ?

If above method does not work and you want to use float right, maybe you can use a non-layout system with FlowPanel maybe. Otherwise you will have to fix the position and width/height of your components but you may loose responsive design.

Last trick : If you really need to change the absolute style. In your component do something like this (do this after your component has been added to the dom)

```
this.getElement().getParent().getStyle().set.....
```

You can reset whatever property you want but this might break your layout

Comment: I agree. Layers should not float. If you need float, use a FlowPanel.

Comment: Its not really a float i want them to be aligned at the right and not at the right side. Actually I have a kind of menu bar with 3 different cells (left, middle, right) while the right one should be also aligned at the right side. Wrapping the Widgets inside the layer into a FlowPanel and then setting them to float: right actually also works but I don't think thats an intended solution though.

Comment: so use setWidgetRightWidth with 0 for right (but need the width of your "cell")

Comment: Is the relative width enough for that?

Comment: Relative width ? I do not understand what you mean. Either you define the width of your component in px and it will be fixed for ever, either you set a % and your design will be responsive. "relative" notion is linked to positioning in css.